# sounds play through both speakers of the laptop and headphone

Tags: sound

I'm using a hp pavilion g6 laptop. sounds play through both speakers of the laptop and headphone. kindly requesting for a solution. thank you!

Comment: Try pavucontrol: Installation via a terminal command: `sudo apt-get install pavucontrol`

Comment: and start it in a termial with `pavucontrol`

Answer (score 0):

1. Open a terminal (by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>).
2. Execute `alsamixer`.
3. Find the `Auto-Mute` option and make sure it's enabled.